# Grand total in oracle interactive report below last row

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I created an interactive report and I want to show the report total value. Is it possible to classic and tabular form. Is it possible in interactive report like classic report compute sum of column value.

Please help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes, it is. In a simple manner. It is an **interactive** report, after all.

- run the report
- click the "Actions" button
- Navigate to "Data"
- Click "Aggregate"

  - Aggregation: New aggregation
  - Function: Sum
  - Columns: select a column name you want to aggregate
- Click "Apply"

If you want to save that report:

- "Actions" (again)
- "Report"
- "Save report"

  - pick whether you want to name it, or save as a default report

Comment: Thanks a lot my brother. but that is for run time session. when i logout and login again then this task again do for sum. But  i want to always show compute sum at bottom row like classic report.

anyway i done my job this way...

*****
select  nvl(to_char(DEPARTMENT_ID),'Total Amount:') DEPARTMENT_ID,
        job_id,
        sum(salary)
  from  employees
  group by grouping sets((),(DEPARTMENT_ID,job_id))
  order by grouping(employees.DEPARTMENT_ID),
           employees.DEPARTMENT_ID,job_id
*******

Comment: You're welcome & I'm glad you did it. **However**, unless you hit a bug in your Apex version, then the last part of my answer ("If you want to save that report ...") does the job. You should save it "**As default report settings**" and its current definition will be used every time.